# Why do delimited files always ask to save after I already have?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'll hit save on a comma and/or tab delimited file - Prompt: "Do you want to keep using this format?" Me: "Yes."

Then when closing the window and without making any changes, a prompt asks me, "Do you want to save?".... "Do you want to keep using this format?" Whether one hits yes or no here, the file will open just as it was saved a moment before.

Anyone know why this is and if there's a config to make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it has to do with formatting inside of excel that CSV files do not support. This includes column width, date formatting, and text formatting.

I'm not sure there is a config option for this as it seems to be a way to fix this as just having the file open in excel adds those formatting options to the temp file that excel uses before writing to the final file.